# Edit "thank you for creating with Wordpress" in version 3.3.1

Tags: admin, cms

Is there a way to edit the text "thank you for creating with Wordpress" in version 3.3.1 at the bottom of the CMS? If so what file do I need to edit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Credit definitely goes to @kaiser, but here is a full working solution.  You can add this code to your functions.php file (in your theme):

```
function wpse_edit_footer() {
    add_filter( 'admin_footer_text', 'wpse_edit_text', 11 );
}

function wpse_edit_text($content) {
    return "New Footer Text";
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_edit_footer' );
```

Answer (score 5):

Just hook into the filter. The only thing remaining will be the `<hr />`.

```
/**
 * Change/Disable the footer text line
 * @return void
 */
function wpse_remove_footer()
{
    add_filter( 'admin_footer_text',    '__return_false', 11 );
    add_filter( 'update_footer',        '__return_false', 11 );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_remove_footer' );
```

In case you want to change it:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', function()
{
    add_filter( 'admin_footer_text', function() {
        echo "This is a custom admin footer text";
    }, 11 );
    add_filter( 'update_footer', function() {
        echo "This is a custom footer update text";
    }, 11 );
} );
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I don't want to remove it though, just edit what it says.

Comment: @Rob Just replace the `__return_false` callback fn for `admin_footer_text` with a custom callback that does a `return` with your custom string.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter('admin_footer_text', remove_admin_footer_text, 1000);

function remove_admin_footer_text($footer_text =''){
return '';  
}

add_filter('update_footer', remove_admin_footer_upgrade, 1000);

function remove_admin_footer_upgrade($footer_text =''){
return '';  
}
```

Comment: Please post a proper answer, that is, please explain what your code does and how it works. File an [edit] and comply

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
// Admin footer modification

function remove_footer_admin () {
    echo '<span id="footer-thankyou">Developed by <a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank">www.example.com</a></span>';
}

add_filter('admin_footer_text', 'remove_footer_admin');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set a very high priority and use some modern programming ? :-)

```
add_filter( 'admin_footer_text', fn () => 'Your custom text', 99, 0 );
```

99 means priority 99 - WP is usually within 0-20 range. It means this will filter last.

If you need to do more logic - use classic anonymous function:

```
add_filter( 'admin_footer_text', function () { return 'Your custom text'; }, 99, 0 );
```

**Unless you are planning to remove a filter/action, please use anonymous/arrow functions.**

(WP has bug for removing anonymous callbacks...)

It makes the code more clear and efficient. If you want to reference the function more times, in modern PHP you can do `functionName(...)` or `$o->methodName(...)`.